# Suggesting similar sentences

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I am trying to create a sentence auto-complete model which will suggest similar sentences.

Problem: I have a sentence corpora of more than 20000 sentences. I want to create a program that would suggest similar sentences to a user as the user types in with his/her keyboard.

for example -

```
user: wh
suggestions: [{'what is your name?'},{'what is your profession?'},{'what do you want?'}, {'where are you?'}]

user: what is your
suggestions: [{'what is your name?'},{'what is your profession?'}]
```

Note:

1. The ordering of words is important, i.e prefix of sentence and user input should be the same.
2. The sentence suggestion are from available text corpora.

My approach:- 
Till now I have only come up with a solution that uses trie data structure to store every sentence in text corpora.

I want to know if there are any machine learning techniques that could be implemented for sentence suggestion that also takes sentence prefix into account.
I would really appreciate anyone who could point me in the right direction.

Comment: If you want to do an exact prefix and there is no probabilistic suggestions involved, I don't see the need to use machine learning here.

Comment: @Unni Keeping the prefix same, there might be many sentences. Suggesting the ones which occur more frequently will involve some sort of language modeling.

Comment: @Will_of_fire: The OP didn't say anything in the question to indicate there is a ranking involved. My comment is assuming a boolean retrieval problem.  A top-k retrieval would involve a ranking step. This may be implemented in several ways. Language models is definitely one of them.

Comment: For sentence suggestion, you have to use ML techniques like Creating tokenizer with vocabulary, Word/Sentence embedding, the semantic similarity between the given and trained sentences can be measured with Euclidean distance, Cosine similarity ... For reference in python check https://pypi.org/project/similar-sentences/

Answer (score 0):

Text generation is a common application of RNNs. Given a sentence prefix the neural network can be trained to predict the most probable next words. 
A very interesting article written by Andrej Karpathy can be found [here](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/)  along with the corresponding [github repo](https://github.com/karpathy/char-rnn).

Another popular method utilizes Markov Chains for text generation (for example see [here](http://agiliq.com/blog/2009/06/generating-pseudo-random-text-with-markov-chains-u/) )

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use Lucene relevency, MoreLikeThis  similar sentence. or you can apply the cosine similarity for same.  hope this will help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Main m = new Main();
    m.init();
    m.writerEntries();
    m.findSilimar("doduck prototype");
}

private Directory indexDir;
private StandardAnalyzer analyzer;
private IndexWriterConfig config;

public void init() throws IOException{
    analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_42);
    config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_42, analyzer);
    config.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);

    indexDir = new RAMDirectory(); //do not write on disk

}

public void writerEntries() throws IOException{
    IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(indexDir, config);
    indexWriter.commit();

    Document doc1 = createDocument("1","doduck","prototype your idea");
    Document doc2 = createDocument("2","doduck","love programming");
    Document doc3 = createDocument("3","We do", "prototype");
    Document doc4 = createDocument("4","We love", "challange");
    indexWriter.addDocument(doc1);
    indexWriter.addDocument(doc2);
    indexWriter.addDocument(doc3);
    indexWriter.addDocument(doc4);

    indexWriter.commit();
    indexWriter.forceMerge(100, true);
    indexWriter.close();
}

private Document createDocument(String id, String title, String content) {
    FieldType type = new FieldType();
    type.setIndexed(true);
    type.setStored(true);
    type.setStoreTermVectors(true); //TermVectors are needed for MoreLikeThis

    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new StringField("id", id, Store.YES));
    doc.add(new Field("title", title, type));
    doc.add(new Field("content", content, type));
    return doc;
}


private void findSilimar(String searchForSimilar) throws IOException {
    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(indexDir);
    IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

    MoreLikeThis mlt = new MoreLikeThis(reader);
    mlt.setMinTermFreq(0);
    mlt.setMinDocFreq(0);
    mlt.setFieldNames(new String[]{"title", "content"});
    mlt.setAnalyzer(analyzer);


    Reader sReader = new StringReader(searchForSimilar);
    Query query = mlt.like(sReader, null);

    TopDocs topDocs = indexSearcher.search(query,10);

    for ( ScoreDoc scoreDoc : topDocs.scoreDocs ) {
        Document aSimilar = indexSearcher.doc( scoreDoc.doc );
        String similarTitle = aSimilar.get("title");
        String similarContent = aSimilar.get("content");

        System.out.println("====similar finded====");
        System.out.println("title: "+ similarTitle);
        System.out.println("content: "+ similarContent);
    }

}
```